# Python dictionary with Decimal

Tags: python, aggregate

I m sure it is a stupid thing but I don t understand why when a query this:

```
from django.db.models import Max
max = Bid.objects.filter(listed=listing_id).all().aggregate(Max('bid'))
```

I obtain `max = {'max_bid':Decimal('3')}`

I want to have a var with max value but if I do this: `maxval = max['max_bid']` I have a `KeyError`.

And if I do this `maxval =  max.values()` I obtain `Decimal('3')`.

I just want to have 3... How can I get this?

Thanks

Comment: I suspect `max` is not actually a `dict`, but some weirdo Django model object that (for unclear reasons) looks like a `dict`. If it were a `dict` as you describe, it would not get a `KeyError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either do not use a [DecimalField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield) (as the entire point of that is to return `Decimal`), or just convert the `Decimal` to whatever type you wanted e.g. integer or float

```py
>>> Decimal('3')
Decimal('3')
>>> int(Decimal('3'))
3
>>> float(Decimal('3'))
3.0
```

Decimal is an arbitrary-precision non-binary floating-point type, it works basically the same as `float` but avoids binary precision loss (not all finite decimal numbers are also finite in binary).